# Using CASE Statement With ROLL UP Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm lumping together several DischargeType values into one category named 'Appeals'. This works fine but the aggregate field MIN(DateReceived) is causing the results to produce 1 DateReceived value for every Appeals type when I just want one for the whole category of Appeals.  I thought I could just add the same CASE statement in the GROUP BY clause but I don't know how to do this with the ROLL UP function. The NULL value in the last row is the totals row. Thanks

```
<PRE>
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_ReportMonthlySAEProcessing] 
@StartDate smalldatetime = NULL,
@EndDate smalldatetime = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
    CASE  
        WHEN DischargeType = 'dqs' THEN 'Disqualifying Status'
        WHEN DischargeType = 'fraud' THEN 'Fraud'
        WHEN DischargeType = 'id theft' THEN 'ID Theft'
        WHEN DischargeType = 'unenforceable' THEN 'Unenforceable'
        WHEN DischargeType = 'unp' THEN 'Unpaid Refund'
        WHEN DischargeType = 'uns' THEN 'Unauthorized Signature/Payment'
        WHEN DischargeType IN ('atb appeal', 'cls appeal','dqs appeal','id 
        theft appeal','unp appeal','uns appeal') THEN 'Appeals'            
    END AS DischargeType 
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN (DateReceived > @StartDate AND DateReceived < DATEADD(dd, 
1, @EndDate)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Claims_Received
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN (DateCompleted > @StartDate AND DateCompleted < 
DATEADD(dd, 1, @EndDate)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Claims_Completed
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN DateCompleted IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Claims_Pending
   ,MIN(DateReceived) AS [Oldest_Claim]     
FROM 
Claims
GROUP BY 
    DischargeType WITH ROLLUP      
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN DischargeType IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, DischargeType</pre>
```

Current Results: [image]

Desired Results: [image]

Comment: Why would you need rollup, when you only group by one field? Or do you have several fields in the full query?

Comment: exclude oldest_claim sum all the claims using dischargetype and then take the min(oldest_claim) group by dischargetype .then cross apply and then filter it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `value` construct :

```
SELECT cc.DischargeType,
       . . .
FROM Claims c CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES (CASE WHEN DischargeType = 'dqs' THEN 'Disqualifying Status'
                     WHEN DischargeType = 'fraud' THEN 'Fraud'
                     WHEN DischargeType = 'id theft' THEN 'ID Theft'
                     WHEN DischargeType = 'unenforceable' THEN 'Unenforceable'
                     WHEN DischargeType = 'unp' THEN 'Unpaid Refund'
                     WHEN DischargeType = 'uns' THEN 'Unauthorized Signature/Payment'
                     WHEN DischargeType IN ('atb appeal', 'cls appeal','dqs appeal','id 
    theft appeal','unp appeal','uns appeal') THEN 'Appeals'            
                END)
      ) cc (DischargeType)
GROUP BY cc.DischargeType WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a CTE 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
WITH claimsGrp AS (
   SELECT
    CASE  
        WHEN DischargeType = 'dqs' THEN 'Disqualifying Status'
        WHEN DischargeType = 'fraud' THEN 'Fraud'
        WHEN DischargeType = 'id theft' THEN 'ID Theft'
        WHEN DischargeType = 'unenforceable' THEN 'Unenforceable'
        WHEN DischargeType = 'unp' THEN 'Unpaid Refund'
        WHEN DischargeType = 'uns' THEN 'Unauthorized Signature/Payment'
        WHEN DischargeType IN ('atb appeal', 'cls appeal','dqs appeal','id 
        theft appeal','unp appeal','uns appeal') THEN 'Appeals'            
    END AS DischargeType 
   ,
   CASE WHEN (DateReceived > @StartDate AND DateReceived < DATEADD(dd, 
1, @EndDate)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Claims_Received
   ,CASE WHEN (DateCompleted > @StartDate AND DateCompleted < 
DATEADD(dd, 1, @EndDate)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Claims_Completed
   ,CASE WHEN DateCompleted IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Claims_Pending
   ,DateReceived AS [Oldest_Claim]     
FROM 
Claims)

SELECT claimsGrp.DischargeType,
       SUM(claimsGrp.Claims_Received),
       SUM(claimsGrp.Claims_Completed),
       SUM(claimsGrp.Claims_Pending)
       min([Oldest_Claim])
        FROM claimsGrp
GROUP BY 
    DischargeType WITH ROLLUP      
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN DischargeType IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, DischargeType
```